# JqueryUI Own widget: Instances overwrite values (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I wrote a little Test to describe my Problem:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $.widget("mseh.testIt", {
            options : {
                foo : false,
                bar : false
            },

            _settedOptions : {
                foo : false,
                bar : false
            },

            readOptions : function() {
                return this._settedOptions;
            },

            _init : function() {
                this._initializeTest();
            },

            _initializeTest : function() {
                var self = this;
                $.each(self.options, function(key, value) {
                    self._settedOptions[key] = value;
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $('#test1').testIt({ foo : true, bar : false});
    $('#test2').testIt({ foo : true, bar : true});

    console.log($('#test1').testIt('readOptions'));
    console.log($('#test2').testIt('readOptions'));

</script>
```

In this example both logs give me a true for 'foo' (as expected) and a true for 'bar' (NOT as expected).

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Tested with jQuery 1.7.2 and 1.9.1.
Tested with jQueryUI 1.9.2 and 1.10.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because _settedOptions shared in every instance of testIt.

if you check _settedOptions's object equality between test1 and test2 as below,
they refers same object.

```
console.log( $('#test1').testIt('readOptions') === $('#test2').testIt('readOptions') );
```

if you want to treat it as instance-variable, write below.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("mseh.testIt", {
        options : {
            foo : false,
            bar : false
        },

        // This field will be shared in every instance.
        // _settedOptions : {
        //     foo : false,
        //     bar : false
        // },

        readOptions : function() {
            return this._settedOptions;
        },

        _init : function() {
            // like this!!!!!
            this._settedOptions = {
                foo : false,
                bar : false
            };

            this._initializeTest();
        },

        _initializeTest : function() {
            var self = this;
            $.each(self.options, function(key, value) {
                self._settedOptions[key] = value;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```